# How to navigate through folders/MAMP?

Tags: php, directory, mamp

This is a pretty simple question that I'm pulling my hair over.

I'm setting up a MAMP server to test my code, the document root is C:/MAMP/htdocs
I set up my folders like this within htdocs:

htdocs -> var -> www -> html -> program -> (code for program/index of program).

At the same time, I have another folder in www. www -> uploads -> (stuff program is supposed to upload to the folder).

I created a test file in uploads called luljokes.txt and then used this code to test if the file exists

```
if (file_exists("/var/www/uploads/luljokes.txt")){
  echo " success !!!!!!!!";
}
else echo " failed ";
```

and it always returns failed.

So my question is, if the document root is at /htdocs/, why can I not access the document through using /var/www/uploads? I'd rather not change my folder structure because I'm altering another project that has the same style.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PHP doesn't care about Apache's document root setting. Your `file_exists` call is looking for a top level directory.  You need to start from `/MAMP/htdocs` (you probably need to include the `C:` as well but I don't code on windows so I'm not sure)

Comment: Since he's using MAMP it's given that he is on a Mac not Windows

Comment: Chad, I'm actually running MAMP on windows. They have a version for it! (I know I should have ran WAMP, but someone suggested MAMP because they used it on their Mac)

Comment: @Cfreak - Sorry, I did not realize that MAMP is made for Windows as well now.  That's funny.

Comment: @Chad I would have thought the same, it just didn't register with me. I saw the `C:`.  Either way it would be true. The docroot doesn't matter to PHP

Comment: @DavidMa - So since you're on Windows, your path of "/var/www/uploads/luljokes.txt" is probably incorrect.  If that file is inside your "htdocs" folder, then just remove the "/" at the beginning.  If not you should find the actual absolute path that probably begins with "C:\path\to\luljokes.txt"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the path file_exists("/var/www/uploads/luljokes.txt") is relative to your document root and not to your file system. This should change to the absolute file system path. Something like: /Users/yourname/MAMP/...

Comment: Because his path begins with "/" his path is not relative, but is actually absolute.  He probably just needs to get the correct absolute path to his file.

Comment: So I tried doing this:
`if (file_exists("C:/MAMP/htdocs/var/www/uploads/luljokes.txt")){
      echo " success !!!!!!!!";
    }
    else echo "failed";
`

But it still says failed. Any advice?

Comment: @Chad looks like var is in htdocs in David's example, so the path David is *trying* to use is relative to htdocs whether he intends that or not.

Comment: @David forward slashes will not work on Windows filesystems. You could try something like `__DIR__ ."var".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."www".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."uploads".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."luljokes.txt"` if you want it to run on multiple platforms.

Comment: @JesseKochis `if (file_exists(__DIR__."var".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."uploads".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."luljokes.txt")){
      echo " success !!!!!!!!";
    }
    else echo "failed ";`

Also didn't work :/

Comment: `echo __DIR__` and see what you get. That should be a good starting point to debugging your problem.